# Converting time between different timezones in java

Tags: java

I want to convert the time from the user to another timezone .I just can't get it right . I can get answers only for current time . And I dont want the date to be displayed.

**The input is time from the user without a date .How do I convert to another timezone?**

```
    String f = (String)c1.getItemAt(c1.getSelectedIndex());
    String t = (String)c2.getItemAt(c2.getSelectedIndex());
    TimeZone fromTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(f);
    TimeZone toTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(t);
    calendar.setTimeZone(fromTimeZone);                                                
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND,fromTimeZone.getRawOffset() * -1);                                
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND,toTimeZone.getRawOffset());
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: You need to show your code. Otherwise how on earth do you expect us to show you what you're doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you've tried - show your code. Also, do a search, because the same kind of question has been asked many, many times before on StackOverflow.

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the java.time classes.

Comment: Parsing strings to get date-time values, and adjusting between time zones, are both topics handled many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search before posting.

Comment: I have searched .My question is i want to convert time alone when date is  not a part of the input.

Answer (score 0):

For now it's not clear what exactly you want/need, so I'm going to post some snippets just in case.
I use ZonedDateTime for this purpose. ZonedDateTime.now() gives you the current date and time. This way you can create any date/time:

```
String zdtString = "2017-01-26T14:00:00+03:00"; // zone UTC +3 hours
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(zdtString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```

Zones can be created this way:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow");
ZoneId zone1 = ZoneId.of("+03:00"); // offset used
```

There are methods to convert ZonedDateTime to another time zone. If you want to get 14:00 in the new zone, use zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Yekaterinburg")).
If you want to know what time is 14:00+03:00 in your zone, use zdt.withZoneSameLocal(yourZone)

If you use zdt.toString(), you will get the default string representation - full data. Of course, you can format ZonedDateTime.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
System.out.println(zdt.format(dtf1));
```

Docs on formatting: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: Good Answer, but if using a mere offset-from-UTC rather than a time zone, use classes `ZoneOffset` and `OffsetDateTime`. If you want to show both zone and offset examples, I suggest you divide the Answer into two parts to show each separately, to be less confusing.